# SQL Insert into Auto_Increment column

Tags: php, sql

Basically, I have a PHP class for generic SQL statements:

1. `object.table('table_name')` fills an array with the column names for `'table_name'` pulled out of the table_schema
2. `object.insert(data_array)` runs an insert statement into `'table_name'` using the column array and the data_array
3. `object.select('where')` returns everything in `'table_name'` using a where statement input or nothing at all

I did this because i'm lazy and I wanted to make my code prettier. However, the schema lookup returns the `ID` columns from my tables, which is fine because sometimes I need it returned with `object.select()`. However, it makes `object.insert()` kinda difficult.

Is there some SQL functionality I don't know about that allows you to insert into an auto incrememented column accurately or is there a more simple solution right in front of my eyes and I'm just being a complete moron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto incremented columns cannot be inserted into.  You can perform your insert (bypassing the auto-incremented field) and just accept the automatically-generated id...

Comment: MySQL does support inserts in an auto incremented field... But of course it is not recomended

Answer (score 1):

You need to omit the id column from the insert statement and use `last_insert_id()` to fetch the last inserted key

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which rdbms you are using, but in SQL server, you can allow inserts into identity column by:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.MyTable ON
```

But I'm not sure why you would want to do that...

Instead, when you do: object.table('table_name'), collect more than just column names, e.g. ColumnName, DataType, IsIdentity, etc. It can by multi-dimensional array, or a class.

Then on insert/select, you can filter out IsIdentity's column. Knowing data types can also be helpful when constructing inserts.